# Множественный выбор

Tags: reactjs

Как на React сделать множественный выбор? Типа как во всяких интернет-магазинах.

[image: DNS] [image: Яндекс.Маркет]

Есть такой готовый компонент? Если нет, то как такой создать?

Comment: [Пример](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-multiple-selection)

Comment: @hindmost, он не так выглядит

Comment: Разумеется не так. Берите стили Semantic UI и правьте под свой вкус. Или вы хотите чтобы все за вас сделали?